# Uniquely identify IPhone on a web application

Tags: iphone, language-agnostic, identification

I have a website and I would like to open it to some of our corporate IPhone users, but without their intervention :

- I enter their IPhone "serial #" into our webapp
- When they connect to the webapp, if their "serial #" is recognised  they can pass, otherwise, access denied.

Is there such a "serial #" ?

I've thought about a SMS with a unique link that will place a cookie. If the cookie is present, they can get in. But if they delete the cookie, they need to call us to get a new unique link.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the uniqueIdentifier property on the UIDevice class.  It's probably your best shot.

Comment: can't access this from a website :)